# бин возвращает null (JSF 2)

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, null

Начал изучать JSF, скачал запустил GlassFish 4 (админовский порт 4848 открылся нормально) развернул проект от Хорстмана (писал он) и в общем при запуске он открывается но свойства бинов там не выводится. Подскажите в чем дело? Буду очень благодарен за помощь[image: JSF вернл null]
  [ссылка на проект](https://yadi.sk/d/It2dk9J23DP9t6)

Вот код:

```
package com.corejsf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named;  
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@Named("user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

   private String name;
   private String password;

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String newValue) { name = newValue; }

   public String getPassword() { return password; }
   public void setPassword(String newValue) { password = newValue; }   
}
```

Comment: Проблемный код должен быть приведён в вопросе, а не быть ссылкой на сторонний ресурс.

Comment: @kff с вирусами еще небось

Comment: Тут проблема не в коде (я не гонюсь за рейтингом) и Ваш негатив могу воспринимать только в конструктивной форме - код выложил Но с вероятностью в 100% вы в нем не чего не обнаружите :) Я просто хотел узнать, может у кого с сервером были такие аномалии.

Answer (score 1):

Так как на Томкат проблемы с отображением нет скорее всего проблема с виндой или glassFish не ровно встал. Приношу свои извинения за возможный негативный осадок от моего глупого вопроса.